# Octave: concise way of creating and initializing a struct

Tags: dictionary, struct, initialization, octave

I have a cell array of strings of length 3

```
headers_ca =
{
  [1,1] = time
  [1,2] = x
  [1,3] = y
}
```

I want to create a `struct` that mimics a python dict, with the values in `headers_ca` as keys (fieldnames in Octave) and an initializer value `ival` for all entries.
It would be a `struct`, since even `dict` exists in octave, [it has been deprecated](https://octave.sourceforge.io/general/function/@dict/dict.html).

I could do (brute force) `s = struct("time", ival, "x", ival, "y", ival);`

**What is the most concise way to do this?**

I know I can do a for loop.
**Can it be avoided?**

I would be working with much longer cell arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [struct](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Creating-Structures.html#XREFstruct) or [cell2struct](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Processing-Data-in-Cell-Arrays.html#XREFcell2struct) to create the structure.

```
headers_ca = {'time','x','y'};
headers_ca(2, :) = {ival};
s = struct(headers_ca{:});

headers_ca = {'time','x','y'};
ivals = repmat({ival}, numel(headers_ca), 1);
s = cell2struct(ivals, headers_ca);
```

Comment: For the first method, since I do not want to modify my `headers_ca`, I would have to first create a copy of it (which is only auxiliary).

Comment: Pointer to another question you may know how to answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437877/extract-values-for-all-row-for-given-fieldname-from-an-octave-struct

Comment: And yet another one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437993/pandas-like-object-in-octave-add-a-field-to-a-struct-by-operating-on-other-fiel