# Extract values for all row, for given fieldname, from an Octave struct

Tags: struct, field, octave

**How can I get all values of a complete column (fieldname), for all rows, from an Octave `struct`?**

I would get it into a cell array, or a regular vector, preferably without looping.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing a few things. Partly because of your equivalence comparison of structs to "R dataframes / python pandas".

Structs are better thought of as being similar to python dicts, R lists, etc. They are a special object that can hold 'fields', which can be accessed by a 'fieldname' ( or values accessed by keys, if you prefer ).

Also, like any other object in octave, they are valid elements for an array. This means you can have something like this:

```
octave:1> struct( 'name', { 'Tom', 'Jim'; 'Ann', 'Sue' }, 'age', { 20, 21; 22, 23 } )
S =
  2x2 struct array containing the fields:
    name
    age
```

In general, when one deals with such a struct **array**, accessing a field on more than one elements of the array, produces a [comma separated list](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Comma-Separated-Lists-Generated-from-Structure-Arrays.html#Comma-Separated-Lists-Generated-from-Structure-Arrays). E.g.

```
octave:6> S(2,:).name
ans = Ann
ans = Sue
```

This can be passed to (i.e. "expanded into") any function that expects such a comma separated list as arguments. E.g.

```
octave:7> fprintf( 'The girls names are %s, and %s.\n', S(2,:).name )
The girls names are Ann, and Sue.
```

If you want, you can also pass that list straight into a 'cell constructor', to create a cell. (though if you want it to have a particular shape, you'll have to reshape it afterwords). E.g.

```
octave:9> reshape( { S.age }, size(S) )
ans =
{
  [1,1] =  20
  [2,1] =  22
  [1,2] =  21
  [2,2] =  23
}
```

There is also `struct2cell` but this does something different. Try it to see what it does (e.g. `C = struct2cell(S)` ).

Finally, to avoid confusion, given the fact that when one deals with struct arrays, "columns" refer to columns in the 'array', I would avoid referring to "fieldnames" by that term.

Comment: The question pointed has (at least one working) answer for this: `myarr = [struc.field]`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio yes this generates a comma separated list, and captures it in brackets, effectively creating a horizontal array. This is effectively the same thing I'm showing here in more detail. But as I said in my other post, you probably aren't looking for an array of structs. You're probably looking for a struct of arrays instead (which would be the closest thing to a dataframe). See my other answer(s) for more details.

Comment: Great, will check that out.