# pandas-like object in Octave: add a field to a struct by operating on other fields

Tags: struct, field, octave

I want to operate in Octave in a similar manner as done with python pandas.
I concluded the most similar object to a dataframe in Octave is a struct.

I have a few related questions.

1. **How can I create a new field 'nf' in struct `mystr`, by operating (row-by-row) on other fields in `mystr`?**
   Say, for fields `a`, `b`, I would like to get `nf = a^b`.
   So far, I am using a loop, which I mean to avoid if possible.

```
    ndata = size(mystr)(1);
    for id = 1:ndata
        mystr(id).nf = mystr(id).a ^ mystr(id).b;
    endfor
```

2. **How can I operate on shifted rows?**
   Say, for fields `a`, `b`, I would like to get `nf[i] = a[i]^b[i-1]` (with proper accounting for `i=1`).
   I guess I can work with a loop as above, but I mean to avoid it.
3. **How can I operate on fixed rows?**
   Say, for fields `a`, `b`, I would like to get `nf[i] = a[i]^b[1]`.
   I guess I can work with a loop as above, but I mean to avoid it.

Comment: You cannot work in Octave the way you do with Python Pandas. Octave is a different language with different strengths. Don't try to shoe-horn a dataframe into a struct, these are different things. If `a` and `b` are scalars for each `id`, then create an array of `a` values and an array of `b` values, and work with these arrays. That is the strength of Octave, and the way you should work there. If you don't want to work with arrays, why use Octave?

Comment: *Total plug warning*: Come try my [Tablicious library](https://github.com/apjanke/octave-tablicious), which provides Matlab-compatible and pandas-dataframe-looking `table` support for Octave. If it doesn't do what you want, feel free to file a feature request on the Issues page.

Comment: There is also the [dataframe](https://octave.sourceforge.io/dataframe/index.html) package in octave forge. There's also `structfun` which performs operations over all fields in a struct. There real question, however, is __why__ do you want to avoid the for loop? It's a perfectly acceptable way of doing it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - I know different languages have different strengths.
I know I can work with cell arrays.
I decided to go with struct since it had named fields, prior to knowing all details on its operation. But it may well be the case the most appropriate class for my needs is a cell array, in which case I would sacrifice the named fields.
Definitely, I would not work with conversions back and forth.
Note the other comments, mentioning that Octave packages *may* give us the best of all worlds (or be in the road to that).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - I will check dataframe. I know about structfun, but it is not what I am looking for now; I do not mean to operate on all fields at a time.
Why avoiding loops? For compactness and readability. But it is certainly not an *enabler*.

Comment: @AndrewJanke - Thanks for the total-plug-warning-pointer. I will check the package and post feedback whenever I have it.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from creating a function `addCalculatedField( S, 'nf', @power, 'a', 'b', ... )` which performs this calculation in whatever way necessary under the hood (including, e.g., a for loop). This would be far more compact and readable, and also good software engineering, since you can also write unit tests for it, as well as separate interface from implementation. If your aim is to replace for-loops with one-liners for "readability purposes", I would strongly urge you against it; typically this results in exactly the opposite coming true.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - But this would not work for an arbitrary expression (power was only an example).

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio this particular function call would, since `@power` is a function handle here. You can replace that with whatever function handle you'd like, as long as it's handled appropriately inside the addCalculatedField function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, using only comma separated lists and `deal`.

```
S = struct( 'a', {1, 2}, 'b', {3, 4} );            % create a struct array
[ S.nf ] = deal( num2cell( [S.a] + [S.b] ){:} );   % deal to new field in array
```

However, I get the impression that you're after one-liners, rather than "efficiency" per se. Don't. This is ugly. There's nothing wrong with a for loop here.

Also, I fully agree with Cris's comment. It's best to rethink your approach. Doing something like the code below is presumably much more preferable than trying to perform operations over struct arrays:

```
S.a = [1,2];
S.b = [2,4];
S.nf = S.a + S.b;
```

I hasten to note that this is effectively what a dataframe is in R too: a bunch of same-sized vectors, each represented by their own fieldname, and packaged inside an object which allows you to access each array by its fieldname.

Comment: I didn't try it yet.
But the `deal`-way seems appropriate, and a one-liner.
Plus, it seems to work for (almost?) any expression/operation I would like to use, even if the sum you used in the example is quite simplistic. Would you agree?
As for the alternative route, I already have a lot of code which uses the structure posted... it would be quite cumbersome to change all that.

Comment: as long as you can end up with a cell that you can index via `{:}` to generate a comma-separated-list of arguments for `deal`, then yes, it'll work. But like I said, I don't necessarily think this is clearer than a for loop (and I highly doubt there's any gain in computational efficiency, though I haven't benchmarked).