# Octave: Differences between struct and cell array

Tags: struct, octave, cell-array

Sparked by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437993/pandas-like-object-in-octave-add-a-field-to-a-struct-by-operating-on-other-fiel) and posted comments/answers, I came up with another question:

**What features are available in [Cell arrays](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Cell-Arrays.html#Cell-Arrays) that are not in [Structures](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Structures.html#Structures), and viceversa, in Octave?**

I could gather the following:

In Cell arrays:

1. Can operate on full "columns" (fields in the structure lingo) at once.

In Structures:

1. Have named fields.

Comment: Given the previous questions, I think what you're really asking is which of the two is "closest" to a dataframe. To which the answer is "neither" (but also "both").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fundamental limitations of cell arrays, arrays of structs, and scalar structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826177/fundamental-limitations-of-cell-arrays-arrays-of-structs-and-scalar-structs)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - Not really.
The answers to this question certainly can at least help approaching what you say. 
But they would be of interest per se, even if dataframes did not exist in our world.
PS: funny "... "neither" (but also "both")."

Comment: @CrisLuengo - I have to read the question and answer it in detail, and possibly test a few things.
On a first read, it has certainly many points in common, and it is quite useful to have it pointed at here.
Even in that case, I am not sure the simple items (just as an example) listed in the OP here are included in the other OP/answer.

Comment: Two points: (1) Equating cell array columns to struct fields is incorrect. You can establish that equivalence in your code if you want, but the two have nothing to do with each other. (2) You cannot operate on full columns of a cell array at once. A column of a cell array (or a row, or any subset of it) is a collection of arrays, and Octave operates on each array independently. There might exist functions that apply the same operation to each element of a cell array (or subset of it), but they are implemented internally with a loop. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) As I state in my other answer, a cell array and a struct array are the same concept: a collection of arrays. Each element of a cell array or a struct array is an array of arbitrary type (a numeric array, a cell array, a struct array, an object array, a handle array, ...). The only difference is in how you index them. Structs have named fields, cell arrays don't.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to answer this, rather than address how they are similar, is to point out how they differ.

Also, since you seem to be drawing equivalents to (and perhaps confusing) concepts from other languages, it may be instructive to point out similarities to constructs from other popular languages, namely R and python.

In all the above languages, there exists the concept of

- an "array": a *rectangular* collection of elements of the *same type*, which can be one or more dimensions, and typically guaranteed to occupy a contiguous area in memory
- a "list": a collection of elements which can be of *different types*, does not have to be rectangular (i.e. can be 'jagged'), typically only 1D (but can be multidimensional, or contain nested lists), and its elements are not guaranteed to occupy a contiguous area in memory
- a "dict": a collection of elements which are like a list, but augmented by the fact that they can be accessed by a 'key', rather than just by index.
- a "table" (?): a horizontal concatenation of equal-sized columns, each identified by a 'column header'

## Octave

In octave, the closest to the "array" concept is the 'object' array, (where 'object' could be anything, but is typically numerical) e,g, [1,2:3,4].

The closest to a "list" concept is the cell array, e.g. { [1,2], true; 'John' }. To index a cell array and obtain the contents of a cell at a particular index, you use `{}`. However, octave cell-arrays are slightly different, in that they can also be thought of as 'object arrays' where the object elements are 'cells', which you could think of as references to their contained objects. This means you can construct a cell-array and index it with `()` as a normal array, returning a sub-array of cells (i.e. another cell-array). Also, a cell can contain another cell-array as its contents (i.e. cell-arrays can be nested).

The closest to a "dict" concept is the struct. This allows you to create an object which can have 'fields', such that for each field you can assign value.

## Python

By contrast, in python you don't have arrays. You only have lists and dicts. In order to get array functionality you need to rely on external modules (such as numpy) which take a list as an argument to convert to an array type. Python lists are also always 1D (but can be nested).

Python dicts effectively behave the same way as octave structs. There are some tiny conceptual differences, but they're effectively equivalent constructs.

## R

R is probably the bit that's causing the most confusion, because R allows you to allocate *names* to elements of both arrays and lists, and allows you to access both using either an index or the allocated name.

But, R still has a vector type, e.g. c(1,2,3), which despite the fact that it can also be given names, e.g. c( a=1, b=2, c=3 ), it still requires that elements need to be of the same type, otherwise R will convert to the least common denominator. (e.g. c(1, '2') will convert both elements to strings).

Then, you have lists, which are basically something like 'lists' and 'dicts' combined. If you have list(1, 2, 3), you have 'list' functionality, and if you have list(a=1, b=2, c=3) you have 'dict' functionality. If you access a list element using the [] operator, the output is expressed as another list   (in a similar way to how cellarrays in octave can be indexed with `()` ), whereas if you index a list using the [[]] operator, you get the 'contents' only  (similar to if you index a cell-array in octave with `{}` ).

## "Tables": dataframes vs dicts vs structs

Now, in R, you also have dataframes. This is effectively a list with names (i.e. 'dict') where all elements are vectors of the same length (but can be different types), e.g. `data.frame( list( a=1:3, b=c('one', 'two', 'three') ) )`; note that expressing this as a data.frame rather than plain list simply results in different behaviour (e.g. printing), but otherwise the underlying object is the same (which you can confirm by typing `unclass(df)`.

In python, we can note that a pandas dataframe behaves the same way (i.e. a pandas dataframe is initialized via a dict whose keys contain values that are equally sized vectors).

Therefore since a dataframe is basically a list of equal vectors, the easiest way to have dataframe functionality in octave is to create a struct whose fields are equal sized vectors. *Or*, if you don't care about fieldnames and are happy to access your contained arrays by "column index", then you can create a cell array and store in each cell your equally-sized numerical 'data' arrays.

## Do cells have "columns" in the way implied in the question?

No. If you want to do vectorised operations, you cannot do it across *cell-array* columns. You need to performed vectorised operations on arrays.

So actually, if what you're looking for is the equivalent of a dataframe, where each "column" represents a numerical vector, the equivalent of that is a struct, where you assign a numerical vector to a field.

In other words the equivalent of dataframes in the various languages are:

- Python: `pandas.DataFrame( { 'col1': [1,2], 'col2': [3,4] })`
- R: `data.frame( list( col1=c(1,2), col2=c(3,4) ) )`
- octave: `struct( 'col1', [1,2], 'col2', [3,4] )`

  Having said that, you may prefer a more 'tabular' output. You can either write your own function for this, or try the `dataframe` package from octave forge, which provides a class for just that.

As an example here's one snippet you could easily convert to a function, and improve on to add all sorts of bells and whistles like colour etc.

```
fprintf( '%4s %5s %5s\n', '', fieldnames(S){:} ), for i = 1 : length(S.col1), fprintf( '%4d %5.3f %5.3f\n', i, num2cell( structfun(@(x) x(i), S) ){:} ), end
   col1  col2
1 1.000 3.000
2 2.000 4.000
```

Comment: To begin with, thanks for taking the time to write a long and detailed answer.
I would have to read, digest, and post feedback.